# Too many re-renders react redux after click of the current link page

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I use redux with react JS the code working normally but i have problem after click the current page link i get error

```
Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

i try to resolve this problem but i don't know why the dispatch function execute after any action response ,
how to stop render or block redirect if the link equal the current page

> Reducer

```js
const initState = {
    isFetching: false,
    isSuccess: false,
}

const tableReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case "GET_CONTENT_PENDING": {
            return {...state, isFetching: false, isSuccess: false,}
            break;
        }
        case "GET_CONTENT_REJECTED": {
            return {...state, error: action.payload, isFetching: false, isSuccess: false,}
            break;
        }
        case "GET_RESTORANT_FULFILLED": {
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: true,
                isSuccess: true,
                moreRestaurents: action.payload.moreRestaurents,
                restaurent: action.payload.details
            }
            break;
        }
        case "GET_CITIES_FULFILLED": {
            return {...state, isFetching: true, isSuccess: true, cities: action.payload.cities}
            break;
        }
        case "GET_RESTO_GROUP_BY_CITY_FULFILLED": {
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: true,
                isSuccess: true,
                restaurantsGroupedBySity: action.payload.restaurantsGroupedBySity
            }
            break;
        }
        case "GET_CITY_RESTORANTS_FULFILLED": {
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: true,
                isSuccess: true,
                cityRestaurents: action.payload.cityRestaurents,
                city: action.payload.city
            }
            break;
        }
        case "GET_MOST_RESERVED_FULFILLED": {
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: true,
                isSuccess: true,
                mostReservedRestaurents: action.payload.mostReservedRestaurents
            }
            break;
        }
        case "GET_TOP_RESTORANTS_FULFILLED": {
            return {...state, isFetching: true, isSuccess: true, topRestaurents: action.payload.topRestaurents}
            break;
        }
        case "GET_ALL_RESTORANTS_FULFILLED": {
            return {...state, isFetching: true, isSuccess: true, allRestaurents: action.payload.allRestaurents}
            break;
        }
        case "GET_CONTENT_FULFILLED": {
            return {
                ...state,
                isSuccess: true,
                isFetching: true,
                content: action.payload.content,
                page: action.payload.page
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return state;
}
export default tableReducer;
```

> Home component

```js
export class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        var cities = this.props.homeState.cities;
        var content = this.props.homeState.content;
        var isSuccess = this.props.homeState.isSuccess;
        var isFetching = this.props.homeState.isFetching;
        var page = this.props.homeState.page == "/home";
        var restaurantsGroupedBySity = this.props.homeState.restaurantsGroupedBySity;

        if (isFetching && isSuccess && cities && content && restaurantsGroupedBySity && page) {
            var cities = this.props.homeState.cities;
            var content = this.props.homeState.content;
            var isSuccess = this.props.homeState.isSuccess;
            var isFetching = this.props.homeState.isFetching;
            var page = this.props.homeState.page == "/home";
            var restaurantsGroupedBySity = this.props.homeState.restaurantsGroupedBySity;

            if (isFetching && isSuccess && cities && content && restaurantsGroupedBySity && page) {
                return (
            } else {
                return (
                    <div className="loader">
                        <img src="/media/images/table-loader.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        homeState: state
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
    return {
        getCities: getCities(dispatch),
        pageContent: pageContent(dispatch, ownProps.match.path),
        getRestaurantsGroupedByCity: getRestaurantsGroupedByCity(dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home)
```

> Actions

```
import axios from 'axios';

export  const getCities =(dispatch)=> {
        let citiesQuery = '/api/get/cities';
        axios.all([
            axios.get(citiesQuery)
        ]).then(axios.spread((cities) => {
            return dispatch({ type: "GET_CITIES_FULFILLED", payload: { cities: cities.data}})
        })).catch (err => {
            return dispatch({ type: "GET_CONTENT_REJECTED", payload: err })
        }); 

        return dispatch({ type: "GET_CONTENT_PENDING"})
}
export const getRestaurantsGroupedByCity =(dispatch)=> {
        let restaurantsQuery = '/api/get/restaurants-group-by-city';
        axios.all([
            axios.get(restaurantsQuery),
        ]).then(axios.spread((response) => {
            return dispatch({ type: "GET_RESTO_GROUP_BY_CITY_FULFILLED", payload: { restaurantsGroupedBySity: response.data}})
        })).catch (err => {
            return dispatch({ type: "GET_CONTENT_REJECTED", payload: err })
        }); 

        return dispatch({ type: "GET_CONTENT_PENDING"})
}
```

Comment: can you share your `getCities`, `pageContent` and `getRestaurantsGroupedByCity` actions ?

Comment: The most possible to get this error is when binding function to element, using the wrong assignment. e.g.  wrong : <input onchange={getSomething(condtion)}  correct: <input onchange={()=>getSomething(condtion)}

Comment: Yes i charge it in load the component dispatch this functions to props connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) i can't use onChange because i need to get data in load page

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems in your code.

The first one is syntax error in your `Home` component:

```js
// ...
if (isFetching && isSuccess && cities && content && restaurantsGroupedBySity && page) {
    // HERE IS SYNTAX ERROR, did you copy your code correctly?
    return (
} else {
// ...
```

The second one is mapDispatchToProps, why you did not do it [according to the documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/6.x/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-a-function). I cannot see your action creators, but generally it should be something like this:

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
    return {
        getCities: (/* action creator args, if any */) =>
            dispatch(getCities(/* action creator args, if any */)),
        pageContent: (/* action creator args, if any */) =>
            dispatch(pageContent(/* action creator args, if any */)),
        getRestaurantsGroupedByCity: (/* action creator args, if any */) =>
            dispatch(getRestaurantsGroupedByCity(/* action creator args, if any */)),
    };
}
```

or even better do not use mapDispatchToProps, just put [object into second argument of connect](https://react-redux.js.org/6.x/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object):

```js
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    {getCities, pageContent, getRestaurantsGroupedByCity}
)(Home)
```

**EDIT (after source code of action creators was added):**

As you are using asynchronous action creators, you should add `redux-thunk` (or redux-saga, but thunk is simplier for beginners) middleware to your redux configuration.
Then you should rewrite your action creators this way (see details the [redux-thunk documentaion](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#why-do-i-need-this)):

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export const getCities = () => (
    (dispatch) => {
        let citiesQuery = '/api/get/cities';
        axios.all([
            axios.get(citiesQuery)
        ]).then(axios.spread((cities) => {
            return dispatch({type: "GET_CITIES_FULFILLED", payload: {cities: cities.data}})
        })).catch(err => {
            return dispatch({type: "GET_CONTENT_REJECTED", payload: err})
        });

        return dispatch({type: "GET_CONTENT_PENDING"})
    }
)

export const getRestaurantsGroupedByCity = () => (
    (dispatch) => {
        let restaurantsQuery = '/api/get/restaurants-group-by-city';
        axios.all([
            axios.get(restaurantsQuery),
        ]).then(axios.spread((response) => {
            return dispatch({
                type: "GET_RESTO_GROUP_BY_CITY_FULFILLED",
                payload: {restaurantsGroupedBySity: response.data}
            })
        })).catch(err => {
            return dispatch({type: "GET_CONTENT_REJECTED", payload: err})
        });

        return dispatch({type: "GET_CONTENT_PENDING"})
    }
)
```

---

**Readability improvements:**

Try to use object destructuring, your code will be more readable (and shorter).

Home (top part)

This:

```js
var cities = this.props.homeState.cities;
var content = this.props.homeState.content;
var isSuccess = this.props.homeState.isSuccess;
var isFetching = this.props.homeState.isFetching;
var page = this.props.homeState.page == "/home";
var restaurantsGroupedBySity = this.props.homeState.restaurantsGroupedBySity;

if (isFetching && isSuccess && cities && content && restaurantsGroupedBySity && page) {
    var cities = this.props.homeState.cities;
    var content = this.props.homeState.content;
    var isSuccess = this.props.homeState.isSuccess;
    var isFetching = this.props.homeState.isFetching;
    var page = this.props.homeState.page == "/home";
    var restaurantsGroupedBySity = this.props.homeState.restaurantsGroupedBySity;
```

can be written like this:

```js
const {homeState} = this.props;
const {cities, content, isSuccess, isFetching, page, restaurantsGroupedBySity} = homeState;
const isPage = page == "/home"; // I suggest to use '===' operator here

if (isFetching && isSuccess && cities && content && restaurantsGroupedBySity && isPage) {
    // you should not declare the same variables here again,
    // the whole this.props is readonly in whole component and will not change
    // (if so there is an error somewhere)
```

Comment: thank you i will test this , yes i copy my code correctly but i don't copy the html page home in condition because it's too long  
 ` if (isFetching && isSuccess && cities && content && restaurantsGroupedBySity && page) {
                return (  html page home )
            }`

Comment: i  update my question to see my actions file, i dispatch the action in axios return,  when i dispatch the action in component i don't get updates when the axios response return because he take some time

Comment: I edited my answer, see details about action creators, I wrote. Can I ask, how are you calling your mapped action creators? They are not called in code of `Home` component you sent.

Comment: I dispatch action in axios response when the action dispatched the Reducer update state i connect the reducer in globale app const store = createStore(tableReducer);

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('tableApp'));

Comment: Yes, but you need to call your mapped action creator somewhere in your component.  You mapped it to props, so somewhere in your component you should call `this.props.getCities()`. See here https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/basic-tutorial#connecting-the-components how mapped action creator `this.props.addTodo` is called in `AddTodo` component.

Comment: yes but i the mapDispatchToProps() function execute when the component called .i call this function in connect because i need the response data in load . its not good practice ? it's good to use componentDidUpdate() instead ? and mapped action creator

Comment: Yes you should do it in lifecycle methods componentDIdMount and/or componentDidUpdate or in some event handler. The best practice how to connect component to redux you can see in my answer.